# Tkinter GUI not displaying anything

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm retrofitting a GUI onto a CLI tool I made that manages screenshots. Whenever I run the file, no GUI appears despite triple-checking the code.

I've tried refactoring and looking for loops that never break, but I haven't found anything. I also compared my code to a few tutorials on Tkinter and haven't seen any problems.

Here's the code:

```
import os, time, shutil
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.path_to_watch = "" # set to wherever your screenshots save by default
        self.new_dir = "" # set to where you want files moved to

        # create widgets
        path_box = Entry(root)
        path_box.pack()

        new_dir_box = Entry(root)
        new_dir_box.pack()

        # continuously fetch input
        while True:
            try:
                path_to_watch = path_box.get()
                new_dir = new_dir_box.get()
            except Exception:
                pass

        # create button that executes the clean
        b = Button(root, text="Clean", command=move_file())
        b.pack()

    def move_file(self):
        directory = os.listdir(path_to_watch)
        words = ['Screen','Shot','Screenshot'] # keywords for default OSX Screenshots

        for i in directory:
            src = path_to_watch + i
            new_dir_filename = new_dir + i 
            filename = i.split()
            for w in filename:
                if w in words:
                    if os.path.isdir(new_dir): 
                        shutil.move(src, new_dir_filename)
                        break
                    else:
                        os.mkdir(new_dir)
                        shutil.move(src, new_dir_filename)
                        break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    AppGUI = App(root)
    AppGUI.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I expect it to build a GUI when it runs, but nothing happens.

Comment: `AppGUI.pack()`? `AppGUI` has no `pack` method.

Comment: `command=move_file()` <- that's the culprit right there

Comment: @Aran-Fey What do you mean by "culprit"?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I fixed it according to the duplicate, didn't work, then just deleted the button and still have the same problem.

Comment: Ah, there's also the `while True:` loop.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while True:` loop was not breaking.